# Android listview inside relative layout

Tags: android

Have somebody implemented ExpandableListView inside layout? I'm trying to do it and I have problems with height. I want to make it "wrap_content" in order to see fully expanded View when it is expanded. But unfortunately with "wrap_content" parameter I cannot achieve this result. Can somebody help?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/user"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/user"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:text="Top User"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="22dp" />

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/elvMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/user"
    android:layout_above="@+id/about" >
</ExpandableListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Bottom About"
    android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Group row in ExpandableListView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <TextView android:id="@+id/groupname"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:textStyle="bold"
  android:textSize="20dp"
  android:paddingLeft="40dp"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
  android:background="@drawable/expanded_upper_selector"
  android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

Child Row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/ingredients_selector">



<TextView android:id="@+id/ingredients_second_layer_text"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:textSize="20dp"
     android:paddingLeft="50dp"
     android:paddingRight="50dp"
     android:textColor="@color/dark_orange"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
     android:gravity="center_vertical"/>
```

Comment: What is the problem with height??

Comment: Height "wrap_content" does not wraps expanded list view.  Expanded list view cannot be seen fully. Just a little part of it can be seen.

Comment: instead of taking ExpandableListView in xml,extend activity by ExpandableListView.That will be more easy

Comment: No Akash, he is also having two textViews, [1]User and [2]About. So ExpandableListView in XML in proper I think.

Comment: Yes, I need to make it inside RelativeLayout

Comment: BTW, Stas, I think you have used different XML for putiing Rows in this ExpandableListView. Can you post your those XMLs??

Comment: Developers of ListView said at Google I/O 2010 that setting "wrap_content" for list-views is one of the worst practices

Comment: Ok, there are two more xml files.

Comment: user1049280, but what is the solution for inserting listViews inside layouts?

Comment: @Stas above layout is OK.two textview one below other.only thing is remove ExpandableListView from it.I have also implemented this thats why i m saying you.

Comment: AkashG, but what is the way to insert ExpandableListView inside? Just from other xml? If yes, can you make an example (brief)?

Answer (score 0):

Try your XML edited some-much:

**Your_XYZ_Main_XML::**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="#000000" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#00ff00" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/user"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:paddingLeft="3dp"
                android:text="Top User"
                android:textColor="#111111"
                android:background="#eeeeee"
                android:textSize="22dp" />
            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/elvMain"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" >
            </ExpandableListView>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/about"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:text="Bottom About"
                android:textColor="#6f6f6f"
                android:textSize="24dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Group_Row_XML ::**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/groupname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#159357"  //  YOUR_BACKGROUND
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
            android:paddingLeft="40dp"
            android:text="Parent text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Child_Row_XML ::**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


<TextView android:id="@+id/ingredients_second_layer_text"
     android:textStyle="bold"
     android:textSize="20dp"
     android:paddingLeft="50dp"
     android:paddingRight="50dp"
     android:textColor="#ff2211"  //  YOUR_COLOR
     android:text="Child Text"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
     android:gravity="center_vertical"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I have an error with circular dependencies.

Comment: In which XML You are getting error with circular dependencies.??

Comment: In main one. Where <ExpandableListView> tag

Comment: I've tried. It works. But I need to paste there ScrollView because I need scrolling. I changed xml in question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14131/discussion-between-chintan-raghwani-and-stas)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link - http://about-android.blogspot.in/2010/04/steps-to-implement-expandablelistview.html

Here only one custom text is added.in similar way you can add second one.Try this and if any query you can feel free to ask.Hope this will help you.

Comment: I do not see any xml there, also I see a simple ExpandableListView. Not inserted in any layout. Just ExpandableListView

Comment: i have clearly written above "Here only one custom text is added".Try this you will get the result.